# In the figure, find the ratio between the segments

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Find the ratio between the segments $\frac{CE}{AE+DE}$
(Answer:$1$)
[image]

(The original figure)

My progress:

From geogebra I believe that the correct figure would have $AB$ and $BC$ tangent to the circumference and some important relationships of similarity and congruence I could not demonstrate.

[image]

$\triangle AEC \sim \triangle EDB \implies \frac{AE}{DE} = \frac{AC}{BD}=\frac{CE}{BE}\\
CE =\frac{AC.BE}{BD}=\frac{BE.AE}{DE}$

$AEDC$ is cyclic

But I couldn't find other relationships

Comment: From the original figure, is $EC$ a tangent of the smaller circle, and is $ED$ a tangent of the larger circle?

Comment: Hello, long time! I hope all is well. The question does not state that $DE$ is a tangent which you are assuming in your diagram. Please see my answer.

Comment: @MathLover Hi, my friend...it's ok with me. What about you?... I'm less present but I haven't stopped posting... as you haven't posted your solutions as usual I thought you were busy with other obligations but I'm glad you're putting your intelligence in plane geometry to help us.

Comment: All well, my friend. Yes, have been quite busy with other obligations and have been able to spend very little time on the site.

Comment: @peterwhy  The question does not mention these data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Say, $\angle CEF = \theta~$ then $\angle AGB = 120^\circ - \theta$

Note that $\angle DBF = \angle DEF = 60^\circ - \theta$

That leads to $\angle BCA = 60^\circ$ and $ACDE$ is cyclic.

As chords $AC$ and $CD$ both make the same angle $(60^\circ)$ on the circle through $ACDE$, they must be equal. So we conclude that $\triangle ACD$ is equilateral.

$ \therefore AD = AC = CD$

Draw angle $60^\circ$ on $EA$ to intersect $CE$ at $H$.

We have $AH = EH = AE$ and $\angle AHC = 120^\circ$

As $\angle ACH = \angle ADE$, $\triangle ACH \cong \triangle ADE$

So we have, $CH = DE$ and $CE = CH + EH = AE + DE$

Comment: Thanks for resolution...So is it not necessary for the point "E" to be a point of tangency?

Comment: My point is that it is not given in the question or it is not clear from the diagram so if you are using that fact, you will have to show it first. But for what we need to find as per question, I would not worry about that part.